# REGEX Google Sheets Conditional

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula in Google sheets.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A3, "BOX OF\s*(\d+)?\s*BOTTLE", "BX-$1BT")

Original                          Expected
BOX OF 3 BOTTLE @ 10 TABLET       BX-3BT @ 10 TABLET
BOX OF BOTTLE @ 10 TABLET         BX-BT @ 10 TABLET
BOX OF 2 BLISTER @ 14 TABLET      BX-2BL @ 14 TABLET
BOX OF VIAL 5 ML                  BX-VL 5ML
```

I would like the formula to work for BOTTLE, BLISTER, etc...

Is that feasable?

Comment: You could use an alternation `BOX OF\s*(\d*)\s*(?:(B)O(T)TLE|(BL)ISTER|(V)IA(L))` https://regex101.com/r/jz83gP/1 and use the capturing groups in the replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get those replacement, one option is to use an alternation with capturing groups for the letters of the words and use the capturing groups in the replacement.

```
BOX OF\s*(\d*)\s*(?:(B)O(T)TLE|(BL)ISTER|(V)IA(L))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jz83gP/1)

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A3, "BOX OF\s*(\d*)\s*(?:(B)O(T)TLE|(BL)ISTER|(V)IA(L))", "BX-$1$2$3$4$5$6")
```

[image]

Comment: IF i complicate the thing, and add to your demo "BOTTLE OF 100 CAPLET" to Get "BT 100 CAPLET"

Comment: The replacement is a bit different. I would use a simpler replacement for that part like match `BOTTLE OF` and replace with `BT` I am not sure if you can use a conditional replacement.